# add and remove text from src on regexp

Tags: jquery

I want to change the src of an image

```
var string = "/images/myimage.png";
```

On button click I want to add `_hover` to myimage (`/images/myimage_hover.png`) and on again button click I want to remove _hover`.

Does anyone have a good idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for `src` attribute to apply your transformations.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 let src = img.getAttribute('src');
 
 src = img.isHover ? 
    src.replace('_hover', '') :
    src.replace('.png', '_hover.png');
 img.setAttribute('src', src);
 img.isHover = !img.isHover;
});

// Use jquery
console.log('2 + 2 =', $(2+2).get(0))
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x100/000/fff?text=image.png"><hr>
<button>Switch</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```